# Как выводить результат с заданной пользователем точностью?

Tags: java, математика, условия, точность

Условие: Написать программу, вычисляющую число   с точностью, задаваемой пользователем. Известно, что сумма ряда 1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-…приближается к значению  pi/4 при достаточно большом количестве членов ряда.

```
public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 3;
        double sum=1;
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){

            if (i%2==0){
                sum=sum-1/a;
            }
            if (i%2!=0){
                sum=sum+1/a;
            }
            a+=2;
        }
        double pi=sum*4;
        System.out.println(pi);

    }
}
```

Само pi я рассчитал, но как задать количество знаков после запятой?

Comment: Точность у вас низковата - всего по порядку величины 1/500...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
String.format("%.2f", value);
```

Взято из:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276096/2871225

Answer (score 1):

От вас требуется не вывести число с определенным количеством знаков, а посчитать с определенной точностью.
Ваш алгоритм делает фиксированное количество шагов

```java
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
```

А должен останавливаться при достижении нужной точности, например так

```java
while (Math.abs(1 / a) > e)
```

где `e` - введенное пользователем число, например 0.0001